# Restricting SXA Script option for non admin Sitecore user

Tags: sxa, sitecore-client, security

Is there any option to restrict non-admin Sitecore users from using the scripts option, that appears on right-clicking of tenant or site node
(Using sitecore 9.3)? Refer to the below image.

The requirement is user should not be able to delete a tenant, clone a site, or delete a site.
[image: the Scripts option on right clicking of a sxa site]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try this? https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/set-up-security-for-a-tenant-and-a-site.html

Comment: @SumitBhatia , I am not able to see any setupsecurity  option under the script.

Comment: It is on a site. Check the insert option of the site, not tenant.

Comment: Furthermore, you can do this by providing security like this. https://kverheire.blogspot.com/2018/06/setting-sxa-security-roles-with-small.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by adding `Rule` on these individual scripts. For e.g. you can go to the below script and in its Rules section, you can add a rule as in snapshot. This will show the script only to `admin` users.

[image]

If you wish, you can hide the entire `Scripts` item in the context menu so that none of these script items are visible to content authors by going to `/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Context Menues/Default/Context PowerShell Scripts` and updating it security field by denying Read access to sitecore Content Author roles. This shall hide the Scripts item itself in the context menu.

There is another different approach which will hide these options in the context menu and disable any PowerShell execution altogether for content authors. This is described in - https://ghanendras.blogspot.com/2022/11/hide-context-menu-items-in-sitecore.html Please be careful if you plan to implement this as any custom implementation dependent on PowerShell script execution will get impacted by this change.